# How to chain where conditions in firebase dynamically, without knowing in advance how many conditions will be set

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working in Angular with firebase.

I want to create a function which will receive two arguments string and object and returns an Observable of filtered data according to object key-value pairs from specific collection *dynamically.*

For example when I will call it this way I expect this result:

```
dynamicFilter('users',{name: 'Jack', age: 30})
```

It should evaluate this call:

```
firebase.collection('users',ref => ref.where('name','==','Jack').where('age','==',30))
```

So I can subscribe to it like:

```
dynamicFilter('users',{name: 'Jack', age:30}).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

I want the function to be universal as I don't know in advance how many conditions will be passed through the object.

I tried this:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore){}

dynamicFilter(collectionName: string, options: object){

    let targetCollection = this.db.firestore.collection(collectionName)
    let query;
    let keys = Object.keys(options)

    for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ){
        if(i === 0){
            query = targetCollection.where(keys[i],'==',options[keys[i]])
        }else{
            query = query.where(keys[i],'==',options[keys[i]])
        }
    }
    return query
}
```

So what can do with this returned value? It is an instance of `Query` class and I guess I can call method `get`, which returns a promise like `query.get().then(res => console.log(res))`.
But the `res` is another instance of `QuerySnapshot` class. How can I simply get data?

Comment: What's wrong with using get() on the query you built?

Comment: here is the result of ```console.log( query.get() )```

```ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data from a `QuerySnapshot`:

```
querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
  console.log(doc.data());
});
```

So:

```
dynamicFilter('users',{name: 'Jack', age:30}).subscribe(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc.data());
    });
})
```

For more on this, see:

- the [Firebase documentation on getting multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).
- the [reference documentation for `QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).

Comment: I've already read many explanations of this kind... the thing is there is no ```data()``` method in querySnapshot class...I'm using ```firebase 5.1.2``` in angular , and there is no such method and many other methods that i encountered on the web

Comment: Sorry sorry )) i found it , it seems like it only available in forEach method...but the next problem is that we can't return that value from promise , we can console.log it but can't reach the result to say 

```dynamicFilter('users',{name: 'Jack', age:30}).subscribe(res => console.log(res))```

where ```res``` is final array

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching all the resources you can imagine , and finally got rid of it and started to experiment on my own , and it's done , it works just perfect you wouldn't have even subscribe to it, it triggers via `Callback` function.

Usecase:

1.You write the code below in service to keep things clear and reusable.

For example let's call it `DataService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {

constructor(private fire: AngularFirestore) { }

dynamicQueryFilter(collectionName: string, options: object, callbackFn: Function): void{

    const bindedCallback: Function = callbackFn.bind(this)

    const targetCollection = this.fire.collection(collectionName).ref
    const optionPairs = Object.entries(options)

    let queryMap = targetCollection.where(optionPairs[0][0],'==',optionPairs[0][1])

    optionPairs.slice(1).forEach(item => {
       queryMap = queryMap.where(item[0],'==',item[1])
    })

    queryMap.get()
      .then(resolve => {
        const documents = []
        resolve.forEach(doc => documents.push(doc.data()))
        bindedCallback(documents)
      })
}
```

2.Then inject it in your component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private db: DataService){}

    users: User[];

    ngOnInit(){
        this.db.dynamicQueryFilter
           (
            'users',
            {name: 'Jack', age: 30, profession: 'Programmer', isMaried: true},
            (res) => this.product = res
           )
    }

}
```

3.Render all married programmers whose name is Jack and who 30 years old in your template

```
<div *ngIf="users">
    <div *ngFor="let user of users">
        <h2>{{user.name}} {{user.surname}}</h2>
        <hr>
        <h4>Additional Info</h4>
        <div><b>Age: </b>{{user.age}}</div>
        <div><b>Profession: </b>{{user.profession}}</div>
        <div><b>Adress: </b>{{user.adress}}</div>
        <div><b>Phone: </b>{{user.phone}}</div>
        //and so on....
    </div>
</div>
```

With this tool in your hand you can do any filtration you may imagine DYNAMICALLY.

You can bind arguments of `dynamicQueryFilter` to inputs or any forms in your template, and let the user perform interactive realtime multi filtration.

Special thanks to Frank van Puffelen for sharing his knowledge.